# binding enter key to asp net linkbutton repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

My question is fairly simple, is there anyway to bind the "enter" key to a asp net linkbutton in repeater? (Iv'e tried `DefaultButton` property, but it did not work. Here is my code:

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Visitor") %>' OnItemCommand="rptVisitedItem_OnItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptVisitedItem_OnItemDataBound" ID="rptVisitedItem">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <asp:Panel Style="float: left;" runat="server" ID="editPanelGroup" Visible='<%# SelectId == Convert.ToInt32(Eval("VisitID")) %>'>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="pHolder" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnGroup" runat="server" ID="editLinkButton" Visible='<%# SelectId != Convert.ToInt32(Eval("VisitID")) %>'>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnGroup" ForeColor='<%# Eval("VisitorGroupID") != DBNull.Value ? Color.Black : Color.Empty %>' ToolTip="TRNSLTVisitorGroupName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VisitorGroupID") == DBNull.Value ? "TRNSLTVisitorGroupName" : Eval("VisitorGroupName") %>' CommandName="selectGroup" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VisitID") %>' />
            </asp:Panel>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C#:

```
private DataSet _groups;
protected void rptVisitedItem_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var panel = (Panel) e.Item.FindControl("editLinkButton");
    var panelT = (Panel) e.Item.FindControl("editPanelGroup");
    var ph = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("pHolder");
    var lbn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnGroup");

    panel.DefaultButton = lbn.ID;
    panelT.DefaultButton = lbn.ID;        
}
```

Is there anyway to do it with JavaScript or jQuery perhaps?

Comment: which button ? will be there more than one button..

Comment: The linkbutton that you see with ID="btnGroup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be anything in your repeater to capture the pressing of the `enter` key. Usually a `DefaultButton` is associated with one or more TextBox controls.

Default browser behaviour is a Form Post when the `enter` is pressed inside an `input type=text` element. So assigning a default button will ensure the correct form is handled withing aspnet.

If you try the snippet below you will see that it works, even without the code in `rptVisitedItem_OnItemDataBound`. Press the enter key when inside a textbox and the corresponding `btnGroup` button will be fired.

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnGroup" runat="server" ID="editLinkButton">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnGroup" runat="server" Text="Test me" CommandName="selectGroup" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VisitID") %>' />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this (requires JQuery):

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

....

protected void rptVisitedItem_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ....
    LinkButton lbn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnGroup");
    lbn.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "__doPostBack('<%= lbn.UniqueID %>', '')");
    ....
}
```

Comment: Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton'.

Comment: No, nothing happens when I press enter.

Comment: Could you please view the page source and look for one of the "btnGroup" and check if it has an "onckeypress" event registered?

Comment: <a id="ctl00_cphMiddleLeft_rptVGrouping_ctl01_rptVisitedItem_ctl00_btnGroup" title="Gruppnamn" onkeypress="$(this).click()" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMiddleLeft$rptVGrouping$ctl01$rptVisitedItem$ctl00$btnGroup','')" style="color:Black;">Grupp X</a>

Comment: Yes, seems like it is registered.

Comment: No, still nothing.

Comment: I am sorry but this approach does not seem to work at all?